Wildcard * search in Google Calendar's Web App
I use Windows 11 and Chrome Browser.
Shocked to discover today that Google Calendar's online Web App doesn't support wildcard * searches.
I've googled the issue, and it's a well-known (and criticized) issue.
Simply put: they don't enable wildcards *.
But maybe some hacker on here has figured out a way around.
So, my question is: have you managed to use part-words successfully in Google Calendar's search? If yes, please share how you did it.

If you are looking for an extension you could search Chrome Webstore or [edit] this question to clearly ask for one and it can be migrated to [softwarerecs.se]. The functionality is not supported as you've noted so a software reccomendation or a web application reccomendation, or writing your own seem like the only possibilities. The first 2 are off-topic and for the  last, we or [so] could help you with as you write it if you have specific problems.
